# Python threading - Is this what I need?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a python script to control various hardware parts of a setup.
I have a state that I want to keep while other parts of the script do their thing.
I think this while loop is stopping other parts of the script from running. 
Do I need to introduce threading so that that loop can continue to run until  I tell it to stop?

Not sure if I am looking at the right method to solve my issue.

edit: 
I have pasted some of  my code the whole thing is quite large.

This listens to a USB MIDI device for messages of specific types and performs actions based on input values which are listed in inst

```
while True:
    b = f.read(1)
    s='rawdataB:'+  hex(ord(b))
    print s

    if b == '\x90':
        note=True
    elif note:
        if b in inst:
            print "IsNote:"  + str( int(hex(ord(b)), 16))
            noteaction(inst.get(b))
        note=False

    if b== '\xB0':
        controller=True

    elif controller:
    #grab the controller with byte 1, value with byte 2
        bcount = bcount +1
        cn=hex(ord(b))  #hex value of byte
        if bcount == 1:
            cntrl=cn
            if cntrl== '0xd':
                fspeedC= 1
                print 'fspeed cnum'     

            elif bcount == 2:
                cval=cn 
        if fspeedC == 1:
            fspeed= int(cval,16)
            print 'fspeed=' + str(fspeed)
            MotorControl('fwd',fspeed,0)
            print 'moving forward'
            print "cn:" + str(cntrl) + ", val:" + str(cval)
            print "bcount: " + str(bcount)
            bcount=0
            cvalue=True

    elif cvalue:
        val=int(hex(ord(b)), 16)
        #print "2val:" + str(val)        
        if val != -1 :
            print "do something" 
            cvalue=False
            print "cn:" + str(cntrl) + ", val:" + str(val)
        controller=False

# this will be a function i guess but also can be in an infinite loop mode when I want it to be
# however while this is running I still want the above code to monitor the incoming MIDI bytes
x=0
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(11, GPIO.FALLING)  
    #prevent bounce
    time.sleep(0.2)
    x=x+1
    print x
    if x % 2 == 0:
         ControlAPairOfPins("17","1","24","0")
         print "Forward"
    else:
         ControlAPairOfPins("17","0","24","1")
         print "backward"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "I have a state that I want to keep" ?

Comment: The question is quite vague.  Could you please show us some code exemplifying your problem?

Comment: Threading sounds like the way to go. It let's a function (with a loop in it) run without blocking the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python `threading` module if you want to leave your loop running while doing something else. The example of that is

```
import time
import threading

def loop(n=10):
    while n>0:
        print n
        n -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
print 'hello world'
t.start()
```

hello world
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need, my next question is how do I control this threaded process by passing parameters to it - stop - for breaking the while loop for instance?

Comment: @Nowski: please read the doc first, there's a lot of things that will become clear https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html , if not feel free to ask questions